# automatically generate new dataset from two data sheets // merge google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google

I have two data sets:

first data set: list of clients who bought a sertain product package:

[image: first data set]

second data set: list of products for every product package:

[image: second data set]

what I need is to generate (automatically) a new dataset where an entry is created for every product that every client has bought:

[image: output dataset]

This is only an example, since the to datasets are huge, copy past is not a solution. Is there even a way to do this in google sheets (appscript?) if not, do you know if this is possible in excel? Thank you very much in advance

here's the editable datasheet, where you'll find the example data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qtxW41ZiA2GbVOrKlD_G5M9xo8hC1GbkIBuAn5wbTnQ/edit#gid=2100307022

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). That looks doable with a lambda formula. Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/168243/edit) the question to show the data and desired results using [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) instead of screenshots. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: tnank you very much for your comment. I just created a table and added it to my sheet. Can you please specify how I can solve my problem with a lambda function? I googled it, but all I can find is, that it creates a custom function :-( do you have an idea what the lambda function would like in this case? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Why do packages have the same name but different products?

Comment: because it's a serial dataset that displays every product that's in a certain product package. You can see it the other way round It's like a list of products that shows the package they're in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reduce()`, `filter()` and `match()`, like this:

```
=lambda( 
  clients, packages, productsAndPackages, packageLookup, 
  reduce( 
    { "Client", "product package", "products" }, unique(filter(clients, len(clients))), 
    lambda( 
      result, client, 
      { 
        result; 
        filter( 
          { iferror(packageLookup / 0, client), productsAndPackages }, 
          match(packageLookup, filter(packages, clients = client), 0) 
        ) 
      } 
    ) 
  ) 
)( 
  A3:A10, B3:B10, E3:F12, E3:E12 
)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qtxW41ZiA2GbVOrKlD_G5M9xo8hC1GbkIBuAn5wbTnQ/edit#gid=1614827959).

Comment: Hey there, I'm really greatful for your help, I tired the formular with data sets in different sheets. in the [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qtxW41ZiA2GbVOrKlD_G5M9xo8hC1GbkIBuAn5wbTnQ/edit#gid=1891261441) it works (see "**Test with multiple sheets**") but when I transfer the formular in my original sheet this error comes up: "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows". I checked the formula a couple of times now and it's the same as in the sample sheet, just with different arrays - do you have an idea why this could be?

Comment: I inserted my formula in the example sheet and I inserted the sesult and the error. I be really greatful if you could take a look

Comment: In your German spreadsheet, you need to use different separators. Replace `{ "Client", "product package", "products" }` with `{ "Client" \ "product package" \ "products" }`.